# How to have different @JsonProperty based on environment in spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, resttemplate

I have a class which is used as a request to hit another service.

It has few fields like below.

```
public class RequestClass {

  @JsonProperty("123")
  private String name;

  @JsonProperty("124")
  private String email;

  @JsonProperty("129")
  private String mobile;

}
```

The upstream service requires the request with field id like 123, 124, 129,etc.

These field id will be different for test and production environment.

Is there any better way to do it other than having different RequestClass?

Comment: What do you mean by _field id_?  Field **name**, field **value**, or something else?  Please provide the expected json for a couple enviornments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a config class where you keep track of the actual id according to your environment and map them using jackson's [@JsonAnyGetter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnyGetter.html).

So for example if you have the following `application.properties` (I'm using [multi-document props](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles#3-multi-document-files) here, but you could also have `application.properties` per profile):

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
#---
spring.config.activate.on-profile=dev
application.requestClass.nameId=123
#---
spring.config.activate.on-profile=test
application.requestClass.nameId=456
```

Then, you'd create your config class (I'm using Lombok's `@Data` for getter/setters):

```
@Configuration
@Data
public class RequestClassConfig {

    @Value("${application.requestClass.nameId}")
    private String nameId;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        RequestClass.config = this;
    }
}
```

and finally your DTO with `@JsonAnyGetter`:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RequestClass {

    public static RequestClassConfig config;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String name;

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> any() {
        final var map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        map.put(config.getNameId(), this.name);
        return map;
    }

}
```

Note that you can do the same for the remaining props, I've just omitted those for brevity.

Now for a quick test run:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
        final var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final var req = new RequestClass();
        req.setName("test");

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(req));
    }

}
```

This will print
`{"123":"test"}` to the console if the `dev` profile is active
and
`{"456":"test"}` if the `test` profile is active.

Comment: thank you so much. It solved my problem 

Comment: Can you please explain the deserialisation part also as the value are becoming null on deserialisation

Comment: Have a look at @JsonAnySetter: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnySetter.html

Comment: This is what I was trying to implement but I am not able to mould it as per the above use case. I have to map {"123":"test"} to {"name":"test"}. I have removed the map inside the any() method and declared it outside. And on doing RequestClass req = new Mapper().readValue("{"123":"test"}", Request.class); these values are getting stored in the map but the "name" field remains as null .Can you please help? @eol

Comment: Ah I see, we'll need to build a custom Deserializer for that use-case. Can you post a new question? I'll add the code there.

Comment: I was able to achieve that. Thank you so much for your support